# Finding magic numbers in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the magic number in this program but I got stuck on this part and am not sure where to go next. I have searched up many ways on the internet but they are all using more complex code that I have not learned yet.

```
Example 
input 45637
4+5+6+3+7 = 25
2+5 = 7
7 = magic number 

num = int(input("Enter a positive number : "))
ans = 0

while num > 0 or ans > 9:
    digit = num % 10
    num = num//10
    print(digit)
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question

Comment: Look into [my answer on recursive-sum-of-all-the-digits-in-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233330/recursive-sum-of-all-the-digits-in-a-number/61234001#61234001) from 2 days ago or [that one thats closer to what you do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236326/7505395)

Comment: `print(num%0)` -- except that if this turns up `0`, you need to print `9` instead.  This is also called the "digital root" of the number.  The digital root of any number in base `k` is `num%k`.  If you want to see the mechanics of this process, look up "casting out nines".

Comment: The thread shouldn't have been closed, because it's not simply an addition of all digits in an integer. It should be opened and edited.

Answer (score 1):

Using statements and operators you have already learned as demonstrated in your code, you can use a nested `while` loop to aggregate the digits from the division remainders into a total as the number for the next iteration of the outer `while` loop:

```
num = 45637
while num > 9:
    total = 0
    while num > 0:
        digit = num % 10
        num = num // 10
        total = total + digit
    num = total
print(num)
```

This outputs:

```
7
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
while len(str(ans))>1:
    ans = sum(map(int, str(ans)))
```

Full code:

```
num = int(input("Enter a positive number : "))
ans = num

while len(str(ans))>1:
    ans = sum(map(int, str(ans)))

print(ans)
```

Output for input 45637:

```
7
```