# Explaining sum of all the digits in a number

Tags: javascript, math

Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has more than one digit, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. The input will be a non-negative integer.

I got one solution and working as expected but it's a bit difficult to understand this.

```
function digitalRoot(n) {
 return (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
}
```

Can anyone helps me to understand this ?

Expected input/output:

```
 16  -->  1 + 6 = 7

942  -->  9 + 4 + 2 = 15  -->  1 + 5 = 6
```

Comment: Hint: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233330/recursive-sum-of-all-the-digits-in-a-number).

Comment: Have you seen: [Explanation of Digital Root/ Sum formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2102877)

Comment: @tadman Example is a bit informative,Thanks

Comment: also: [Why is ((−1)mod9)+1 equal to summing all digits till one digit is left?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789533/why-is-n-1-mod-91-equal-to-summing-all-digits-till-one-digit-is-left)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this solution :

```
const getSum = (num) => {
    if((""+num).length>1){
        const size = (""+num).split("").reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0);
        return size>9 ? getSum(size) : size;
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}
getSum(12344) // 1+2+3+4+4 --> 14 --> 1+4 --> 5
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: the output should be the sum of all the digits present. and if the sum contains more than 1 digit, then repeat.

Comment: The question asks about an explanation of why `(n - 1) % 9 + 1` yields the digital root; it does not ask for some other digital root algorithm.